# NebulaGraph Database: How to write data with spark-connector in pyspark?

Tags: nebula-graph

In the example, I saw the way of writing data in scala. Is there a way to write nebulagraph data in python?

```
/spark/bin/pyspark --driver-class-path nebula-spark-connector-3.0.0.jar --jars nebula-spark-connector-3.0.0.jar

df = spark.read.format(
  "com.vesoft.nebula.connector.NebulaDataSource").option(
    "type", "vertex").option(
    "spaceName", "basketballplayer").option(
    "label", "player").option(
    "returnCols", "name,age").option(
    "metaAddress", "metad0:9559").option(
    "partitionNumber", 1).load()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `pyspark` is already supported by `nebula-spark-connector`.
The related issue has been addressed and closed [on Github Issue #19](https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula-spark-connector/issues/19).

If you search "pyspark" on the Github project [README](https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula-spark-connector), you'll see some examples.
Just make sure that you set the paths to the spark-connector jar file in SparkConf before starting your spark application.

An example taken from the README:

```py
df.write.format("com.vesoft.nebula.connector.NebulaDataSource").option(
    "type", "vertex").option(
    "spaceName", "basketballplayer").option(
    "label", "player").option(
    "vidPolicy", "").option(
    "vertexField", "_vertexId").option(
    "batch", 1).option(
    "metaAddress", "metad0:9559").option(
    "graphAddress", "graphd1:9669").option(
    "passwd", "nebula").option(
    "user", "root").save()
```